# How can I stop a javascript event from firing another (different) event?

Tags: javascript

I have an onkeydown event that may or may not scroll the page, and may or may not set a variable. I would like to have an onscroll event that sets that variable to false. I do not want the onkeydown event to trigger the onscroll event. How can I do this?

edit: Added my code. It lets you use your left and right arrow keys to move up and down through the images on my page. Sorry it's so wide.

```
<script>
    window.anImageHasBeenCentered = false;

    window.onkeydown = function ( key )
    {
        var element = document.elementFromPoint ( window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 );

        if ( anImageHasBeenCentered ) // move to next image
        {
            switch ( window.event ? event.keyCode : key.keyCode )
            {
                case 37: element = element.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.firstChild; break; // Left Arrow
                case 39: element = element.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild; break; // Right Arrow
                default: anImageHasBeenCentered = false; element = null;
            }
        }

        else // center current image
        {
            switch ( window.event ? event.keyCode : key.keyCode )
            {
                case 37: break; // Left Arrow
                case 39: break; // Right Arrow
                default: element = null;
            }
        }


        if ( element )
        {
            element.scrollIntoView ( );

            if ( ( window.innerHeight + window.scrollY ) < document.body.offsetHeight ) // if we are not at the bottom of the page
            {
                if ( element.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight ) // if the element is shorter than the screen
                { window.scrollBy ( 0, -( ( window.innerHeight - element.offsetHeight ) / 2 ) ) } // position it in the middle of the screen
            }

            anImageHasBeenCentered = true;
        }
    };

    // The function I would like to add, that is unfortunately triggered by the onkeydown function.
    // window.onscroll = function ( ) { anImageHasBeenCentered = false; }
</script>
```

Comment: If you can show some code, one can help you for sure

Comment: Have you given the event.stopPropagation() method a look? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Comment: Yes. As I understand it, stopPropagation only prevents events of the same type from firing. Not events of another type.

Comment: Events are thrown by the Browser regardless if you decide to handle them or not; you can't stop that behavior. JavaScript is event driven. You can add an event handler with `addEventListener` and remove it with `removeEventListener`. Those are your options. The rest is just application logic.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I don't know if I can really guarantee it will always work, but it has so far. I just used setTimeout to delay setting my variable to true until after onscroll sets it to false.

```
window.anImageHasBeenCentered = false;

window.onscroll = function ( ) { anImageHasBeenCentered = false; };

window.onkeydown = function ( key )
{
   var element = document.elementFromPoint ( window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 );

   switch ( window.event ? event.keyCode : key.keyCode )
   {
      case 37: // Left Arrow
         if ( anImageHasBeenCentered ) element = element.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.firstChild;
         break;
      case 39: // Right Arrow
         if ( anImageHasBeenCentered ) element = element.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild;
         break;
      default: element = null;
   }


   if ( element )
   {
      element.scrollIntoView ( );

      if ( ( window.innerHeight + window.scrollY ) < document.body.offsetHeight ) // if we are not at the bottom of the page
      {
         if ( element.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight ) // if the element is shorter than the screen
            window.scrollBy ( 0, -( ( window.innerHeight - element.offsetHeight ) / 2 ) ); // position it in the middle of the screen
      }

      window.setTimeout ( function ( ) { anImageHasBeenCentered = true; }, 1 );
   }
};
```